# What PC VGA connector used 2 rows of pins?

Tags: vga, connector, identify-this-peripheral

I remember that 20 years ago (around the year 2000) I came across a few computers with a weird monitor connector. They weren't old computers, but rather budget mainstream computers of the time period. I believe that one of them was a Pentium 3 or a Celeron.

The connector was very similar to standard VGA 15-pin connector, but the pins were laid out in 2 rows instead of 3. I don't remember how many pins there were, but I remember that I was surprised that it looked very similar to the standard COM port (RS-232) connector. However the monitor at the other end was a very standard CRT monitor (for the time). I think the connector was also for the on-board graphics on the motherboard, not a separate graphics adapter.

I'm curious as to what kind of standard that was. I can't find it on the Internet.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649475/does-vga-db15-have-the-same-pinout-as-vga-de15 may be relevant.

Comment: @JonCuster - That was what jogged my memory and inspired this question! :)

Comment: [Mini-VGA](https://pinoutguide.com/Video/mini_vga_connector_pinout.shtml) uses two rows but I wouldn’t expect that in a budget PC at the turn of the century.

Comment: @StephenKitt - Definitely not it. It resembled (or maybe even was identical, I don't recall)  a DB9 connector.

Comment: Are you saying these cards had ONLY this connector, or in addition to the standard VGA connector? If it was in addition, it was likely something proprietary to that brand of video card. A 2-row 15-pin video connector also sounds like a Macintosh video connector.

Comment: By looking at https://pinoutguide.com/Video/, I also can't find something that would match.

Comment: @TimLocke - No. That was an onboard graphics card (not a separate one) and that was the only video connector.

Comment: The Macintosh and monitors for it used a DB-15 connector similar to that of a game port.  I wouldn't find it astonishing if there existed some PC graphics cards that used the same connector.

Comment: @supercat Do you mean DA-15? Because a DB-15 is unlikely to exist.

Comment: @Justme: Hmm... a web search shows things being sold as DB-15 which look like the connectors in question.  Maybe the terminology isn't correct, but it's a connector with the same pin spacing as DB-25 and DB-9, but with rows of eight and seven pins.

Comment: @supercat Yes, that is a common problem and people use wrong names. The letter means the connector shell size and the number means pin count. You have DE-9 for EGA and DE-15 for VGA, DA-15 for game port, and DB-25 for parallel port.

Comment: @Justme: Sorta funny, because I recall back in the 1980s I always heard Atari joystick connectors called DB-9 and never DE-9.

Comment: @supercat It is a common misconception since D-Subminiature (D-Sub) connectors were established, that the most common form at that time (DB-25 for RS-232) hat "DB" as shorthand for D-Sub. It is best to not assume a plug size of someone writes DB, and accept the pedants that insist on DA-15 and DE-9. In context of this question, this pedantry makes sense because we are discussing DE-15 (VGA) vs. DA-15 (AUI).

Comment: It's not on a PC, so I didn't post it as an answer, but my brother bought a used Tektronix oscilloscope which included the video output option board, and it uses a DE-9 connector for VGA that you're supposed to convert to DE-15 using the passive cable that originally came with it.

Comment: @ssokolow Interestingly enough I can easily find many passive "VGA converters" from a 9-pin to a 15-pin connector even on Amazon. So that suggests that there is some sort of standard out there somewhere...

Comment: @Vilx-  many passive 9-15 pin VGA adapters on dodgy websites yes, but that doesn't mean they sell many.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I doubt they sell many, especially today, however the very fact that they exist means that there is (or used to be) a demand for them.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be CGA, MDA or EGA connector (DE-9) (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors#D-subminiature_family) ?

The Pentium *!!!* era doesn't match, but on Wikipedia, there is this note that states :

> Early VGA cards also used this connector

Comment: I'm pretty certain that it wasn't that old. Definitely after 1997, and the computer was a consumer-grade middle-to-low-end PC. Windows 95 or 98. The monitor was a full-color CRT (don't remember the resolution, but definitely 16 or 32 bit full color).

Comment: I TEND to remember a DE-9 for a monitor. But it would have been at best for a 486 computer, maybe even a 286. Forgive my - lacky - memory: it was more than thirty years ago^^

Comment: @Olivier It MIGHT have been a Trident TVGA8800CS : 16-bits ISA, DB-15 **and** DE-9. Still, 1988. And definitely discrete video card.

Answer (score 3):

One option is that it was a Matrox video card which had a VGA connector and additional connector for the Rainbow Runner Studio daughter board. Though it was 15-pin DA-15 connector like used for Game/MIDI port and for Ethernet AUI port, not 9 pin DE-9 like used for RS-232 mouse.

Some early VGA cards did use DE-9 for VGA, and also some early cards had also a DE-9 for backward compatibility with older EGA/CGA/MDA monitors, but the time frame of about 2000 did not have those any more.

A similar looking video connector would be the Japanese D-terminal connector, but unlikely too.

Some cards had all kinds of custom ports for TV and 3D glasses but unlikely again to be DE-9 as that era started to use the Mini-DIN for anything television related.

Comment: I distinctly remember that the monitor itself connected to the weird port. And no, it wasn't the Japanese D-terminal.

Comment: The monitor was purchased around 1994/1995 (486 to Pentium era) I don't know exactly as it was my employer that had bought it. I just kept the computer and the monitor when I left the company in compensation of what they owed me.

Answer (score 2):

The 1984 [Professional Graphics Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Graphics_Controller) used a DE-9 connector (the same connector as MDA, CGA and EGA) with analogue signals compatible with those used later by VGA. A similar [9-pin connector](https://www.retro-kit.co.uk/page.cfm/content/9-pin-to-15-pin-VGA-Adapter/) was used by 32-bit Acorn computers in the late 1980s. It appears also to have found its way onto some PC video cards, as it is documented on various websites as "[9-pin VGA](https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/computer_video/vga-9-pin/)".

All implementations seem to follow the PGC pinout, except that they have separate horizontal and vertical sync where the PGC has a single composite sync signal:

1. Red video
2. Green video
3. Blue video
4. Horizontal sync (PGC: composite sync)
5. Vertical sync (PGC: either not connected, or select 400/480 lines)
6. Red ground
7. Green ground
8. Blue ground
9. Sync ground

Comment: OP says budget mainstream computers but this PGC was very obscure and expensive. Are you saying it just because someone recently made a Youtube video mentioning it?

Comment: Why would you need/want a separate ground for each of RGB and sync?

Comment: @OmarL For three coaxial video cables you need tree grounds for the cable shields. This is high speed analog stuff going at high frequencies and high slew rates.

Comment: @OmarL The analog monitor is supposed to have 75 Ohm input impedance. That means that ~10mA current flows through each of the red/green/blue video lines, and that currents needs to return to the graphics card through a ground line. The current through the ground conductor is dropping a voltage across the ground conductor, *shifting ground potential*. A high-quality video cable provides different ground conductors for red/green/blue (possibly as coax shields) and a high-quality monitor sends the return current through the individual pins and uses differential sensing. This will eliminate...

Comment: ... cross-talk between the color channels due to ground current from the other channels shifting a common ground potential.

Comment: @user253751 While 9-pin analog video on PC video cards is rare, a 9-pin input is commonly used on TTL/analog switchable CRT monitors, like the NEC MultiSync II (which is way more common than a PGC). In analog mode, they often use the variation of the PGC layout with separate sync (sometimes supporting CSYNC as well), so this is actual useful knowledge about "VGA on 9 pins".

Comment: @user253751: No, I started with the PGC because that's the earliest use of the pinout that I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the acorn archimedes 9 pin used a different pinout, and had the ability to feed back one of the sync signals and have it mixed with the other. So depending on how you wired the connector you could either have a combined sync signal for feeding to RGB scart or seperate sync signals for feeding to a VGA style monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Hyundai 17" monitor that has as input a [DA-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature). The cable has a normal [DE-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) on one side and the very unusual [DA-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) with 4 missing pins on the other side. The monitor also has a 5 BNC input (R,G,B,Vsync, Hsync) which allows to use the monitor if one would lose the very difficult to procure [DA-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) to [DE-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) cable.

I don't know if there was a graphic card or computer that used [DA-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) as  output but there is definitely a VGA monitor using as input.

Comment: Nice! :) Now I'm starting to wonder if perhaps I remember the wrong end of the cable? It was over 20 years ago after all...

Comment: I can try to determine the pinout of the cable this week-end if people are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be SGI's OpenLDI connector?

Somewhat more obscure port that looks like a cross-breed of SCART, serial port & VGA.

Couldn't find an English site, but this one has a photo of the connector and a display adapter:

https://www.journaldulapin.com/2017/03/31/sgi-1600sw/

When I started in computer science in -99, we had those SGI comps around with all sorts of weird interfaces.

Comment: No, not really, sorry.

Comment: That's just an ordinary "Centronics" connector seen on any parallel port printer from the days before USB took over the world ;-)

Comment: @TooTea No it isn't. OpenLDI uses the smaller MDR connector with 0.05" pitch. Printers used the larger MDR connector with 0.085" pitch. Besides many printers just used the same DB-25 instead of MDR before USB took over.

Comment: @Justme OK, didn't pay that much attention, but I would still describe it as "looks like a Centronics" than "a cross-breed of SCART, serial port and VGA" (which at least I can't readily visualize).